# Move Ordering in Javascript Chess Engine chess.js

Tags: javascript, chessboard.js

i am by far a javascript specialist but i am trying to learn it a little.

For the move ordering in my chess engine (i follow a tutorial), i would like to check for captures first.
In the chess.js library the capture moves are listed with the flag 'c'.

```
game.moves({ flags: 'c', verbose: true })
```

so im trying to make a shopping list with first the capture moves, and after that, all the rest moves.
i tried it like this:

```
var children = [                                                                    
    [game.ugly_moves({ flags: 'c', verbose: true })],
    [game.ugly_moves({ verbose: true })]
];
```

like this:

```
var children = [game.ugly_moves({ flags: 'c', verbose: true })] + [game.ugly_moves({ verbose: true })];
```

But nothing seems to work.

My code can be seen at http://users.telenet.be/gianc/chessai/js/main.js at line 153

Playable [here](http://users.telenet.be/gianc/chessai/)

other info: https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js/blob/master/README.md

Any input is greatly appreciated!

TIA

Comment: "Nothing seems to work" is not diagnostic. Are you trying to concatenate two arrays?

Comment: I apologize i am not native english, by nothing i mean the examples above dont work. I dont know what concatenate means. Edit: i googled concatenate and yes, thats what i am trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation at https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js/blob/master/README.md#moves-options-, the `flags` are not passed into `moves()`, but rather, are returned from `moves()` as an attribute associated with each legal move.  Therefore, to get a list of all captures, you will need to apply a filter on the resulting array of all legal moves.  Something along the following lines...

```
let allLegalMoves = game.moves( { verbose: true } );
let captures = allLegalMoves.filter( move => move.flags.includes( 'c' ) );
```

Note the use of `includes()` as there can be multiple flags per move.

**EDIT:** As a follow up to my original answer, another option is to assign values to the `flags`, and create a new attribute associated with each move called, say, `importance`.  This new attribute will be constructed by assigning values to the critical flags and summing the flags to get an `importance` ranking for each move, and then sorting the moves in descending order.

For example, let's say that promotions ('p' flag) are most important followed by captures ('c' flag) followed by anything else.  Let's then assign, say, the value of 16 for each 'p' flag, and 8 for each 'c' flag.  Note that in this case that a promotion that also captures will have a sum of 24 putting this move at the top of the list(!).

The code will appear as follows...

```
let allLegalMoves = game.moves( { verbose: true } );

for ( let move of allLegalMoves ) {
  move.importance = 0
    + move.flags.includes( 'p' ) ? 16 : 0
    + move.flags.includes( 'c' ) ? 8 : 0;   
}

allLegalMoves.sort( ( a, b ) => b.importance - a.importance );
```

And of course there's nothing prohibiting you from including other factors to feed into `importance` to aid in ranking the moves...

Comment: While that `=> 0 <=` really looks fancy, there exists an https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: lol.  yes, the use of `includes()` will make it less syntactically confusing.  i'll adjust `0 <= move.flags.indexOf( 'c' )` to `move.flags.includes( 'c' )`...

Comment: Afters this point i made ```var children = [ [captures], [allLegalMoves] ];``` but still, this does not work

Comment: @GiCl90 take a look at the edit I just included, which doesn't break the array apart, but rather ranks the moves and then sorts by ranking...

Comment: @Trentium thank you very much for your effort, i understand what you did. But unfortunately it still doesnt work

Comment: @Trentium it doesnt make moves, i change "allLegelMoves" to "children" ofcourse for all the references. I also used var because it is used outside the function to. To be clear, it does work when i use ```var children = game.moves()```

Comment: @GiCl90 what I posted is simply ranking the moves per your question.  Analyzing and making moves is a whole other subject, typically involving the minimax algorithm coupled with various algorithms that assess the position...

Comment: @Trentium yes AlphaBeta works when i use the default ordering. Check the website in the question

Comment: @GiCl90 sounds like you need to walk via the debugger the variations of using the default ordering vs the ranked ordering, to narrow down the specific issue.